# How to output a directory structure (stored in database) as a JSON message with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, webapi

I have a directory structure stored in an SQL Server database. So when a client calls the Web API, it should return the structure as a JSON message.

The database table looks like this (this is just a sample, there are a lot more of rows than this):

```
Id  Name            ParentId    RootId
1   Directory 1       NULL        1
2   Directory 1.01     1          1
3   Directory 1.02     1          1
4   Directory 2       NULL        4
5   Directory 2.01     4          4
6   Directory 3       NULL        6
7   Directory 3.01     6          6
```

The returned JSON message should look like this:

```
"structure": [
      {
        "value": "Directory 1",
        "label": "Directory 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "Directory 1.01",
            "label": "Directory 1.01"
          },
          {
            "value": "Directory 1.02",
            "label": "Directory 1.02"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "Directory 2",
        "label": "Directory 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "Directory 2.01",
            "label": "Directory 2.01"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "Directory 3",
        "label": "Directory 3",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "Directory 3.01",
            "label": "Directory 3.01"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Here are some additional notes:

- When the RootID has an value (the same as the Id) and the ParentId is NULL, it's the root directory (like Directory 1).
- A parent directory can have multiple levels of subdirectories (or children). My example just showed one subdirectory under one top directory.

What kind of LINQ query I should create to get out the JSON message as described? Can't wrap my head around this...

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit broad, no?

Comment: Do you want to select whole tree or just leaf based on some criteria?

Comment: What is the problem: how to read the database into a collection of similar items, or how to convert a collection of similar items to a string in JSON format?